# Как правильно прочитать лямбда выражение в Java?

Tags: java, android

```
List<Staff> staff;

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Staff x : staff) {
            result.add(x.getName());
        }

List<String> collect = staff.stream().map(x -> x.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Не могу понять последнюю строчку. Также значение x -> x.getName() и .collect(...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вызвать метод `getName` для каждого элемента списка `staff` и собрать из полученных значений список `collect`.